# woocommerce variations (Dropdown) not behaving as expected

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am configuring a shop on woocommerce, I have added 128 variations combined of
STYLE
SIZE
COLOR

for tshirt store.

But on selecting particular style say "hoodie Tshirt" I must see only white and black colors in Color dropdown, But I get all colors from color attribute in dropdown.

What May be the problem? Please help

Comment: Go the variations tab of your product metabox and remove the undesired variations.

Comment: They are not undesired,I need all.

Comment: When I select style from 1st drop box, I want only 2 colors to get loaded in second dropdown. But its loading all colors for each style dropdown.
I have manually configure 128 vriation